# How to completely release memory when activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, out-of-memory

The detail activity has 3 fragments that feed the tabbed view, one of the tabs can hold images that the app downloads from an API and turn them into bitmap to set them to ImageViews that are in the rows of a carousel.

When I go back to the main activity, the DetailActivity goes to a onPause() state and does not releases memory, so if I enter and exit the detail activity several times the app crashes.

This is the code that I use to go back to the main activity, also if I use the this.finish() method it does not releases memory

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when(item?.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
                this.onBackPressed()
                finishActivity(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

[image: This is the console error]

How can I make the app to destroy all the resources used in the detail activity instad of sending the activity to onPause() state.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't manually release memory in Android. Garbage collector doing that for all object without active links.

Comment: "When I go back to the main activity, the DetailActivity goes to a onPause() state" -- with `finish()`, your activity will be called with `onPause()`, `onStop()`, and `onDestroy()` in rapid succession. "so if I enter and exit the detail activity several times the app crashes" -- you are attempting to allocate 19,834,892 bytes of memory in a single block. That is huge, much larger than you should be trying to allocate, particularly when you want multiple images. You need to take the size of your `ImageView` into account when loading the image. Glide and Picasso handle that for  you.

Comment: Are you using an image loading library like Picasso or Glide? If not You should look into doing so as they are very good at loading images with minimal memory usage

Comment: If you are using `finishActivity` to end the current activity, you shouldn't. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) states that the finishActivity() is used to force finish another activity. So you should `finish()` instead.